# difference between int and Integer type in groovy

Tags: groovy, types, type-conversion, groovyshell

I have just started learning groovy and I am reading "Groovy in Action".
In this book I came across a statement that **it doesn’t matter whether you declare or cast a variable to be of type int or Integer.Groovy uses the reference type ( Integer ) either way.**

So I tried to assign **null** value to a variable with type **int**

```
int a = null
```

But it is giving me below exception

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead
>       at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:2)

Then I tried to assign **null** value to a variable with type **Integer**

```
Integer a = null
```

and it is working just fine.

Can anyone help me understand how `groovy` behaves such way or the reason behind it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The core problem is that [primitives](http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2013/08/20/groovy-primitive-data-types-vs-classes) can’t be null**. Groovy fakes that out with [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

If you store a `null` value in a number, you can’t store that in a `int/long/etc` field. It’s not correct to convert a `null number` to 0, since this might be valid values. `Null` means that no value or choice has been made yet.

`int` is a [`primitive type`](http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2013/08/20/groovy-primitive-data-types-vs-classes) and it is not considered as an `object`. Only `objects` can have a `null` value while `int` value can't be `null` because It's a value type rather than a reference type

For [`primitive types`](http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2013/08/20/groovy-primitive-data-types-vs-classes), we have fixed memory size i.e for `int` we have `4 bytes` and `null` is used only for `objects` because there memory size is not fixed.

So by default we can use :-

```
int a = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Groovy uses wrapper types in all time when you **call** primitives

```
int a = 100
assert Integer == a.class
```

groovy takes int and wrap it into Integer before using it value
But groovy cannot set int value to null, because variable is int(primitive type) but not Integer.

```
int a = 100
int b = 200
a + b not int + int, but Integer + Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, Groovy uses the wrapper types if you use literals. For example:

```
def a = 11 // equivalent to Object a = 11. 11 is an java.lang.Integer
```

or

```
assert ['java.lang.Integer'] == [ 11, 22, 33 ]*.class*.name.unique()
```

Although if you use a specific type in your definition, the compiler has to perform casting.

You can do:

```
def a = 11
a = 'ssss'
```

but

```
int a = 11 // or int a
a = 'ssss'
```

gives `GroovyCastException`.

This what you see in your case

Comment: Sorry but I am still not able to understand the reason.